# Aligining Icon and text like a listing dot in a proper appearance - how?

Tags: html, css

I need help with the following code. I am SUPER NEW and just learned html and css. Well lets say I am still learning. I want this icon displayed and right next to it the text. The problem is that the ico) is not properly aligned to the text. As you can see (picture) the text is not properly aligned. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

[issue - german web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R5vy.jpg)

```html
<html>
<title>
Was wir anbieten
</title>
<body>
<style>
img{
position: relative; top: 25px;}
</style>

<p>

<h2>

<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>  &nbsp; Ihre gewünschte Werbekampagne
  </h2>
  </p>
  
  <p>
  <h2>  
  
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/> &nbsp; Professionelle Bild- und Videoaufnahemen + Bearbeitung

  </h2>

  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use positioning for this case. This is a case of fixed-fluid:

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Or

```
+-------+-----------+
| FIXED | FLUUUUUID |
|       | FLUUUUUID |
+-------+-----------+
```

Fixed-Fluid Model. In my snippet, I have demonstrated two kinds of examples. In the first case, the fluid is less in size. And the next has too long content.

**Snippet**

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 0 0 15px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; padding-left: 100px;}
.parent .fixed {position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}
.parent .fluid {background-color: #f99;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
  <div class="fluid">Fluid Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque animi placeat, expedita tempora explicabo facilis nulla fuga recusandae officia, maiores porro eaque, dolore et modi in sapiente accusamus id aut.</div>
</div>
```

**Solution**

1. Do not add any other tags inside `<p>` tag. Not a good idea.
2. Use semantic markup, please!

**Working Snippet**

```css
.parent {position: relative; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 5px; padding-left: 100px; min-height: 50px;}
.parent .fixed {position: absolute; left: 5px; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}
.parent .fluid {}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></div>
  <div class="fluid">The Text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fixed">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></div>
  <div class="fluid">A longer text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus magni ipsam facilis laboriosam nesciunt eveniet obcaecati dicta laborum voluptatem reiciendis, possimus vel enim. Dignissimos assumenda ipsa aut. Facere, unde animi.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Any chance to center "The Text" so its not on the top line of the picture?

Comment: Yes, you can do. Just give `top: 50%` instead of nothing on the left hand absolutely positioned one.

Comment: Do you mean .parent .fixed {position: top: 50%; width: 90px; background-color: #99f;}

Comment: @Nino Sorry for responding late. I was having my dinner. There you go: **http://output.jsbin.com/naqicunuto**. Use the last CSS.

Comment: Thank you again so much for your response which helped me a lot. I hope I do not bother you but I still have some problems with my page. Do you mind if I contact you private message?

Comment: @Nino Sure. You can do so. You have my email address in my profile page.

Answer (score 0):

Set your image as "inline-block"

```
img{display:inline-block}
```

Anyway, i suggest you to use "ul" "li" to do it http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp